# Iterate over multiple columns and replace the values in these columns after a row (increment) with null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
          date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0    2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1    2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2    2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3   2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4   2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5   2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6   2021-10-31  3547.3361  3421.161235  3481.911001  3456.474600
7    2021-11-7  3491.5677  3370.140147  3439.284539  3416.621024
8   2021-11-14  3539.1002  3319.289523  3391.930037  3370.079953
9   2021-11-21  3560.3734  3261.343723  3333.984237  3312.134153
10  2021-11-28  3564.0894  3255.328902  3338.967086  3305.054247
11   2021-12-5  3607.4320  3313.274702  3396.912886  3363.000047
12  2021-12-12  3666.3479  3371.220502  3450.172564  3412.234440
13  2021-12-19  3632.3638          NaN  3466.930383  3428.683490
14  2021-12-26  3618.0535          NaN          NaN  3370.737690
```

Let's say the columns after `value` column (`20211003`, `20211010` and `20211017`) are rolling forecast result of `value`, instead of 10 values for each column, I'll need to keep 3 values only and get the result as follows:

```
         date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN  3481.911001  3456.474600
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN  3416.621024
```

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

Comment: how do you chose which date/value to keep? is it important? Also do you only have a single stretch of data per column, or several?

Comment: 1. From left to right, from top to bottom, so row `2021-10-10` from column `20211003` will be the starting point, and then increase day by day; 2, Yes, one single stretch of data per column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a single stretch per column, use a `cumcount` of the non-NA values to determine which ones to keep, then slice and reindex each column:

```
cols = ['20211003', '20211010', '20211017']
N = 3

# compute cumcount of non-NAs, leave NAs as NA
cc = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.groupby((m:=s.notna())).cumcount().where(m))

# get the mask for the date/values columns
m1 = ~cc.min(1).gt(N)
# compute the mask for the first N non-NA
masks = ~cc.ge(N)

# mask and reindex per column with default m1 for date/values
out = df.apply(lambda s: s[masks[s.name] if s.name in masks else m1]
                         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output:

```
         date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN  3481.911001  3456.474600
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN  3416.621024
8  2021-11-14  3539.1002          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do u mind add comments on what do `cc`, `m1` and `masks` represent respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
a = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3))
df.iloc[df.index <= a.index.max(),:2].join(a)
```

Out:

```
        date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN  3481.911001  3456.474600
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN  3416.621024
```

Option 2:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3)).pipe(lambda x: df.iloc[df.index<=x.index.max(), :2].join(x))
```

Out:

```
         date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN  3481.911001  3456.474600
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN  3416.621024
```

Option 3:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3)).join(df.iloc[:,:2])
```

Out:

```
      20211003     20211010     20211017        date      value
3  3510.221000          NaN          NaN  2021-10-10  3592.1666
4  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN  2021-10-17  3572.3662
5  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400  2021-10-24  3582.6036
6          NaN  3481.911001  3456.474600  2021-10-31  3547.3361
7          NaN          NaN  3416.621024   2021-11-7  3491.5677
```

Comment: Very concise answer, thanks for sharing.