# Iterate over multiple columns and replace the values a prior a row (increment) with null values in these columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe df as follows:

```
          date      value     20211003     20211010     20211017
0    2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1    2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2    2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3   2021-10-10  3592.1666  3510.221000          NaN          NaN
4   2021-10-17  3572.3662  3465.737012  3534.220800          NaN
5   2021-10-24  3582.6036  3479.107035  3539.856801  3514.420400
6   2021-10-31  3547.3361  3421.161235  3481.911001  3456.474600
7    2021-11-7  3491.5677  3370.140147  3439.284539  3416.621024
8   2021-11-14  3539.1002  3319.289523  3391.930037  3370.079953
9   2021-11-21  3560.3734  3261.343723  3333.984237  3312.134153
10  2021-11-28  3564.0894  3255.328902  3338.967086  3305.054247
11   2021-12-5  3607.4320  3313.274702  3396.912886  3363.000047
12  2021-12-12  3666.3479  3371.220502  3450.172564  3412.234440
13  2021-12-19  3632.3638          NaN  3466.930383  3428.683490
14  2021-12-26  3618.0535          NaN          NaN  3370.737690
```

Let's say the columns after value column (`20211003`, `20211010` and `20211017`) are rolling forecast result of value, instead of 10 values for each column, I'll need to keep 3 values only. Here is the slicing rule: from left to right, from bottom to top to keep 3 values for each date column, so row `2021-11-28` from column `20211003` will be the starting point, and then increase day by day. The expected result will like this:

```
          date      value     20211003     20211010    20211017
0    2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN         NaN
1    2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN         NaN
2    2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN         NaN
3   2021-10-10  3592.1666          NaN          NaN         NaN
4   2021-10-17  3572.3662          NaN          NaN         NaN
5   2021-10-24  3582.6036          NaN          NaN         NaN
6   2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN          NaN         NaN
7    2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN         NaN
8   2021-11-14  3539.1002          NaN          NaN         NaN
9   2021-11-21  3560.3734          NaN          NaN         NaN
10  2021-11-28  3564.0894  3255.328902          NaN         NaN
11   2021-12-5  3607.4320  3313.274702  3396.912886         NaN
12  2021-12-12  3666.3479  3371.220502  3450.172564  3412.23444
13  2021-12-19  3632.3638          NaN  3466.930383  3428.68349
14  2021-12-26  3618.0535          NaN          NaN  3370.73769
```

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

**Reference:**

[Iterate over multiple columns and replace the values in these columns after a row (increment) with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486252/iterate-over-multiple-columns-and-replace-the-values-in-these-columns-after-a-ro#73486252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:, :2].join(df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().tail(3)))
 
          date      value     20211003     20211010    20211017
0    2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN         NaN
1    2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN         NaN
2    2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN         NaN
3   2021-10-10  3592.1666          NaN          NaN         NaN
4   2021-10-17  3572.3662          NaN          NaN         NaN
5   2021-10-24  3582.6036          NaN          NaN         NaN
6   2021-10-31  3547.3361          NaN          NaN         NaN
7    2021-11-7  3491.5677          NaN          NaN         NaN
8   2021-11-14  3539.1002          NaN          NaN         NaN
9   2021-11-21  3560.3734          NaN          NaN         NaN
10  2021-11-28  3564.0894  3255.328902          NaN         NaN
11   2021-12-5  3607.4320  3313.274702  3396.912886         NaN
12  2021-12-12  3666.3479  3371.220502  3450.172564  3412.23444
13  2021-12-19  3632.3638          NaN  3466.930383  3428.68349
14  2021-12-26  3618.0535          NaN          NaN  3370.73769
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this concise solution, is it possible to do so for this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486252/iterate-over-multiple-columns-and-replace-the-values-in-these-columns-after-a-ro#73486252

Comment: @ahbon change the function call `tail` to `head`

Comment: @ahbon if you want the exact reproduction of what you have, you could do `df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3)).pipe(lambda x: df.iloc[df.index<=x.index.max(), :2].join(x))`

Comment: @ahbon or you could do `a = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3));df.iloc[df.index <= a.index.max(),:2].join(a)`

Comment: @ahbon `df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x:x.dropna().head(3)).join(df.iloc[:,:2])`

Comment: Thanks, do u mind put your answer to that question?

Comment: @ahbon which one of the three do you want me to post?

Comment: All of these methods are all pretty good. :)